# Problema con conversión de base64 a imagen, muestra solo 25% de la imagen

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, sql, base64

Tengo una api que su funcion es:

1- Tomar datos de mi FrontEnd.

2- Esos datos enviarlos a mi tabla en SQL Server.

Uno de esos datos, es una foto que llega convertida en Base64, y lo guardo en mi campo en SQL que es un varchar(max), bien, hasta ahi todo perfecto.

El problema esta en que cuando voy a corroborar que ese string de Base64 sea la foto que le pase (cuando voy a convertir ese base64 a imagen de nuevo), **la misma me sale cortada** , solamente aparece 1/4 de imagen podria decirse.

No se a que se debe este pequeno problema de verdad, y no puedo ubicar en que parte de mi programa estaria el error, si en FrontEnd, en mi API, o en SQL Server.

Dejo mi codigo.

FRONTEND en Javascript y Jquery Mobile.

```js
var gImg;

function SacarFoto() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
    });

    function onSuccess(imageData) {
        $("#fotoCapturada").html('<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData + '" width=100% >');
        gImg = imageData;
        copyFile(imageURI, 'MiFoto.jpg', LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY) // no se que funcion cumple esto
    }

    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }
};


function EnvioDatosDeposito(idComprobante, fecha, foto, comentarios) {
    var dir = "InsertarDatos";
    var datos = {
        idComprobante: idComprobante,
        fecha: fecha,
        foto: foto,
        comentarios: comentarios
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: api + dir,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;base64",
        data: JSON.stringify(datos),
        success: function(esta) {
            if (esta == true) {
                $("#pMensaje").html("Datos enviados satisfactoriamente.")
            } else {
                $("#pMensaje").html("Ha ocurrido un error en el envio de datos.")
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("error en ajax");
        }
    });
}


function Enviar() {
    var txtidComprobante = $("#idComprobante").val();
    var txtfecha = $("#dtFecha").val();
    var txtcomentarios = $("#txtComentarios").val();
    EnvioDatosDeposito(txtidComprobante, txtfecha, gImg, txtcomentarios);

}
```

API en ASP.NET

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("InsertarDatos")]
    public bool InsertarDatos([FromBody]datos dato)
    {

        string strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MiConexion"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(strCon);
        bool esta = false;
        string query = "INSERT INTO EnvioDeposito(idComprobante,fecha,foto,comentarios) VALUES (@idComprobante,@fecha,@foto,@comentarios)";
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(query, conexion);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idComprobante", dato.idComprobante);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", dato.fecha);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@foto", dato.foto);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comentarios", dato.comentarios);
        try
        {
            conexion.Open();
            int filas = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (filas > 0)
            {
                esta = true;
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conexion.Close();
        }
        return esta;
    }
```

Creacion de tabla en SQL Server

```
create table EnvioDeposito( idDeposito int identity(1,1),
                        idComprobante int unique not null,
                        fecha varchar(20) not null,
                        foto varchar(max) not null,
                        comentarios varchar(max),
                        primary key(idDeposito, idComprobante)
                        )
```

Lo que se, es que en alguna parte del codigo, me esta acortando el base64, y es cuando se envia el formulario de mi frontend a mi api.

Probando con postman y harcodeando un base64 completo, llega perfecto.

Esta seria la imagen que me muestra, una ves convertida de base64 a imagen

[image: asi me muestra la imagen una ves convertida de base64 a imagen:]

**Edicion**

Me he dado cuenta que mi problema esta al enviar la peticion mediante ajax, que me esta mandando el base64 cortado.. AJAX tiene un limite de envio de datos? Se puede configurar eso?.

He averiguado y una de las soluciones podria ser agregarle a mi web.config de mi api esto :

```
<system.web.extensions>
<scripting>
  <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/>
  </webServices>
</scripting>
```

Y esto:

```
    <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="2147483647  " />
```

Pero sigo sin encontrar solucion alguna.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99392/discussion-on-question-by-tato8vio-problema-con-conversion-de-base64-a-imagen).

Answer (score 5):

Tu error esta al momento de guardar el `string` **`Base64`** en la **BD**, te dejo un ejemplo de una imagen cortada por el **string** incompleto

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var srcImagen = 'data:image/png;base64,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';
  $("#imagen64").attr('src', srcImagen);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="" id="imagen64" >
```

Esta seria la imagen completa a mostrar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Valida el **Snippet**, estas guardando de forma incompleta el **`string Base64`** en tu Base de datos

Comment: si, me he dado cuenta que al momento de enviar el string base64 desde mi aplicacion > hacia mi api, me lo esta cortando dejando un 25% de imagen, asi como tu me mostras en el ejemplo.. Pero sigo sin poder encontrar solucion

Answer (score 0):

Revisa que tu metodo de conversion no este cortando los caracteres. o mejor aun, usa archivos blob, convierte tu base64 a blob.

me paso que cortaba mi base64 exactamente a 512000 caracteres.

codigo en typescript:

```
getb64toBlob(b64: string): Blob {
const b64toBlob = (b64Data: string, contentType: string = '', sliceSize: number = 512) => {
  const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
  const byteArrays = [];

  for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
    const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

    const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
      byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
  }
  return new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
};

let contentType: any = b64.match(/data:([a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9-.+]+).*,.*/) || false;
if (contentType) {
  contentType = contentType[1];
} else {
  contentType = '';
}
const b64Data = b64.substring(13 + contentType.length);
return b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType);}
```