# Mi Captcha no muestra todos los colores

Tags: html5, php7, base64

## Actualmente

Implemente la clase Captcha en PHP y quiero saber porque al utilizar `base64` me esta descolorizando el output de `picture()`. Me explico, he estado refactorizando una pagina web que hice anteriormente, cuando no sabia mucho, luego de muchas horas de esfuerzo pude crear un captcha en una pagina estatica, el problema era que utilizando variables globales como `$_SESSION` perjudican la seguridad. Este captcha es utilizado en una pagina web que hace una consulta como `form`, al final de todo pude abstraer la clase de la siguiente manera.

#### Captcha.php

```
    class Captcha {
    private string $keyword;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->keyword = $this->generateKey(5);
    }

    private function generateKey(int $len) : string {
        /* algoritmo q genera una clave aleatoria */
        return $random_string;
    }

    public function picture() {
        $image = imagecreatetruecolor(150, 50);
        imageantialias($image, true);

        $colors = array();

        for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
            $colors[$i] =
                imagecolorallocate(
                $image,
                mt_rand(125, 190) - 20 * $i,
                mt_rand(125, 190) - 20 * $i,
                mt_rand(125, 190) - 20 * $i
                );
        }

        imagefill($image, 0, 0, $colors[0]);

        for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            imagesetthickness($image, mt_rand(2, 10));
            $line_color = $colors[mt_rand(1, 4)];
            imagerectangle($image, mt_rand(-5, 150), mt_rand(-5, 10), mt_rand(-5, 180), mt_rand(40, 60), $line_color);
        }

        $fontcolor = array(
            imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0),
            imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255));

        $font = array(
            dirname(__FILE__).'/fonts/a.ttf',
            dirname(__FILE__).'/fonts/b.ttf',
            dirname(__FILE__).'/fonts/c.ttf');

        for($i = 0; $i < strlen($this->keyword); $i++) {
            $letter_space = 140 / strlen($this->keyword);
            $initial = 5;

            imagettftext($image,
                30, mt_rand(-20, 15),
                $initial + $i * $letter_space, mt_rand(30, 40),
                $fontcolor[mt_rand(0, 1)], $font[array_rand($font)],
                $this->keyword[$i]);
        }
        ob_start();
        imagepng($image);
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    public function key() : string {
        return $this->keyword;
    }
}
```

#### index.php

```
<?php 
/* Solo para testear */
include_once(Captcha.php);
$captcha = new Captcha();
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($captcha->picture()).'"/>'; ?>
```

### RESULTADO ACTUAL

[image: despues1] [image: despues2] [image: despues3] [image: despues4]

## Anteriormente

Este es el codigo antiguo, el cual reproduce imagenes sin el problema de la decolorizacion.

#### Captcha.php

```
session_start();

$permitted_chars = 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ';

function generate_string($input, $strength = 10) {
    $input_length = strlen($input);
    $random_string = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $strength; $i++) {
        $random_character = $input[mt_rand(0, $input_length - 1)];
        $random_string .= $random_character;
    }

    return $random_string;
}
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(150, 50);
imageantialias($image, true);

$colors = [];

$red = rand(125, 190);
$green = rand(125, 190);
$blue = rand(125, 190);

for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $colors[] = imagecolorallocate($image, $red - 20*$i, $green - 20*$i, $blue - 20*$i);
}

imagefill($image, 0, 0, $colors[0]);

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    imagesetthickness($image, rand(2, 10));
    $line_color = $colors[rand(1, 4)];
    imagerectangle($image, rand(-5, 150), rand(-5, 10), rand(-5, 180), rand(40, 60), $line_color);
}

$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$textcolors = [$black, $white];

$fonts = [dirname(__FILE__).'/fonts/a.ttf', dirname(__FILE__).'/fonts/b.ttf', dirname(__FILE__).'/fonts/c.ttf'];

$string_length = 5;
$captcha_string = generate_string($permitted_chars, $string_length);

$_SESSION['captcha_text'] = $captcha_string;

for($i = 0; $i < $string_length; $i++) {
    $letter_space = 140/$string_length;
    $initial = 5;

    imagettftext($image, 30, rand(-20, 15), $initial + $i*$letter_space, rand(30, 40), $textcolors[rand(0, 1)], $fonts[array_rand($fonts)], $captcha_string[$i]);
}

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
```

#### index.html

```
<!--Luego de un monton de divs y formatos de posicion sin filtros-->

<div>
    <img src="captcha.php" width="150" height="50" alt="captcha">
</div>
```

### RESULTADO ANTERIOR

[image: antes1] [image: antes2] [image: antes3] [image: antes4]

Como podran notar los resultados las imagenes se muestran decolorizadas y no se porque sucede. Me gustaria que me ayudaran a solucionarlo **para que termine como los resultados anteriores**.
Si hay alguna sugerencia para mejorar el codigo porfavor haganmelo saber.
Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: ¿no están al revés las imágenes? Yo veo la primera en blanco y negro y la segunda en color

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez habilita la libreria gd en php

Comment: @Marcos gracias por responder, estoy actualizando mi pregunta para dejar mas en claro el problema de la decoloracion

Comment: Mira esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/297835/problema-con-conversi%C3%B3n-de-base64-a-imagen-muestra-solo-25-de-la-imagen puede que ayude

Comment: @AsielCabreraGuerrero hola, esa respuesta utiliza javascript, aca estoy haciendo todo meramente en PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El cambio de color no se debe al `base64`, sino que se debe a que **ANTES** generabas los colores `blue, green y red` y los usabas como base, modificandolos unos puntos menos, para crear otros (*en la misma gama*).

#### Solución:

Tenes que cambiar esto:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $colors[$i] =
        imagecolorallocate(
        $image,
        mt_rand(125, 190) - 20 * $i,
        mt_rand(125, 190) - 20 * $i,
        mt_rand(125, 190) - 20 * $i
        );
}
```

Por esto:

```
$red = rand(125, 190);
$green = rand(125, 190);
$blue = rand(125, 190);

for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $colors[] = imagecolorallocate($image, $red - 20*$i, $green - 20*$i, $blue - 20*$i);
}
```

Comment: @EgonStetmann. las imágenes que obtengo ahora son como [esta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr2Ia.png). Entiendo que es el resultado que estas necesitando. Si te fijas, el código anterior "congelaba" la base para crear los demas colores, dando como resultado el efecto de color en la misma gama.